# Find the minimum and maximum of $g(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \left|x-a_k \right|$

Tags: calculus

> Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence. Find the minimum and maximum of $g(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \left|x-a_k \right|$.

**Attempt**:

We have $g(x) =  |x-a_0|+|x-a_1|+\cdots+|x-a_n|$ and by the triangle inequality $\left|(n+1)x-(a_0+\cdots+a_n)\right| \leq g(x)$. Doesn't this show there is no minimum value to the function since equality can always be achieved?

Comment: Maximum certainly can't be attained since you can choose $b_n = n+ \max{a_i}$, and $b_n > a_i$ for all $i$ and $n$. Then $g(b_n)$ can be made arbitrarily large.

Comment: Right, my question now is about the minimum.

Comment: We can take successive terms: $|x-a_0|+|a_1-x| \geq a_1-a_0$, etc.

Comment: the minimum is achieved at the median:  $x = \frac12 \left(a_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} + a_{\lceil(n/2\rceil}\right)$

Comment: @achillehui I don't think that is right.

Comment: There can be infinitely many $x$ at which the minimum is attained.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How do I find this minimum?

Comment: I once (or twice) wrote it out  in detail on MSE. Imagine a bug starting well to the left of $a_0$, and crawling rightward. For a while, each little step of length $\Delta$ decreases the sum by $(n+1)\Delta$. When the bug reaches $a_0$ and takes a tiny step, the sum decreases by $(n-1)\Delta$. Continue. After a while, the sum begins to increase. But for example if $n+1=6$, there is no change from $a_2$ to $a_3$, the minimum is reached at all $x$ in $[a_2,a_3]$. (Like Catalin Zara, I would prefer if the indices had range $n$.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas I need a formal calculus argument for this, but I like this idea.

Comment: It can be made formal with the appropriate inequalities (treat odd number of points and even number of points separately). Not really calculus, we will not be using the derivative, which at the important points does not exist.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That was actually my idea sort of. We can apply the triangle inequality to two terms at a time $|x-a_0|+|a_1-x| \geq a_1 -a_0$ etc. depending upon if $n$  is odd or even. We just need to prove that equality can hold.

Comment: Now that we know the answer, the details should not be hard. Do the odd number of points first. Let our points be $a_1$ to $a_7$ (I changed the indexing). Show that the minimum is at $x=a_4$, by showing that if $x\lt a_4$ our sum is larger than at $x=a_4$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I still have to show this for the general case.

Comment: If you can do $7$ and $8$ you can do the general case.